# What's the biggest BigInt value in js as per spec

Tags: javascript, bigint

It turns out (outer a bit of thought it's more obvious but whatever) that [BigInt](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/bigint) recently introduced to javascript has a limit:

[image]

My question would be - is there a constant similar to `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` but for BigInt?

This snippet of code:

```
   let a = 2n, step = 1;
   try{while(true) {
      console.log(step); 
      a=a**2n; step++
   }} catch(e){ console.log(e)}
```

Shows that the limit is about (step = 32) - at least in Chrome. But I wonder what it this value as per spec.

Comment: Is this actually part of a spec yet, or has Chrome just added in-built support for things that were previously available via js libraries?

Comment: Looks like [it's a candidate spec](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint) that Chrome (and a few others) are already supporting.

Comment: From: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/bigint
// Highest possible BigInt value that can be represented as a
// signed 64-bit integer.
const max = 2n ** (64n - 1n) - 1n;

Comment: @JamesThorpe  Not sure it's something you could polyfill with a js lib, as it's also got primitive number format, something you could transpile of course.  Babel seems to have the syntax plugin for it, but couldn't find the compiler part.

Comment: Seems, it is `(((1n << (2n**30n - 1n)) - 1n) << 1n) | 1n`.

Answer (score 27):

It seems like there is no maximum limit to a BigInt as per [spec](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-bigint/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-bigint-type), which makes sense considering BigInts are supposed to be [arbitrary-precision integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), whose "digits of precision are limited only by the available memory of the host system".

As for v8 specifically, according to [this article on the v8 blog](https://v8.dev/blog/bigint#tl%3Bdr), the precision of BigInts are "arbitrary up to an implementation-defined limit". Unfortunately, I couldn't find any further information on how the limit is determined. Maybe someone else would be able to shed light on this based on these [v8 BigInt implementation notes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1n3tBP90XibvnHMFCY3vdhvkXHFp2joSZp7qnqBtn0PU)?

That said, based on the aforementioned articles, there doesn't seem to be a specific maximum value/size for a BigInt. Rather, it is likely determined based on the available memory on the system in some way.

Comment: Correct, there is no spec-defined limit. Last I checked, Firefox and Safari both allowed up to 1 million bits, which is probably more than enough for all practical purposes. V8 (Chrome/Node/Opera/Edge/...) currently allows up to 1 billion bits. As the limit is implementation-defined, each engine could change it in the future (in either direction).

Answer (score 11):

The maximum size of a BigInt in webkit is defined as such

```
  // The maximum length that the current implementation supports would be
  // maxInt / digitBits. However, we use a lower limit for now, because
  // raising it later is easier than lowering it.
  // Support up to 1 million bits.
  static constexpr unsigned maxLength = 1024 * 1024 / (sizeof(void*) * bitsPerByte);
```

The size of void* is platform dependent, 8 on 64 bit systems.

So there's your answer right? Should be 16384 bits.... (-1 for the sign). But I can't create anywhere near that large a number in console.

Comment: @Alec: the comment clearly says "Support up to 1 million bits". Creating such BigInts in the console is easy if you don't try to manually type out their decimal representation. For example, `BigInt('0x' + 'f'.repeat(250000))` will have exactly 1 million bits, so will `2n ** 999_999n`.

Comment: @Keimeno: The limits you've posted are for 64-bit integers. A 16384-bit integer can get much bigger, up to 2^16383, which has 4933 decimal digits and hence doesn't fit into this comment. Since BigInts in WebKit support up to a million bits (currently; WebKit developers might change this in either direction), they can grow up to (2^1000000) - 1.

Comment: 16384 bits (which gets you over 4900 decimal digits) occupies about 2KB of memory.  The spec, however, implies that the limit should be guided by "available memory", suggesting that decent implementations should allow *much* more.  In theory, ranges in the hundreds of millions of decimal digits, given that I have successfully used strings that are over 200 million characters in in-browser JavaScript implementations.  Any limit lower than this would show that implementations are imposing their own much more conservative limits.

Comment: @thomasrutter I know what the spec says, but in practice there has to be a limit defined somewhere. My response is taken from the source code of chromium to show what, at least at the time, the value actually was.

Comment: @jmrk I understand that is what the comment says, but the comment is just a comment and the math that actually defines that variable doesn't work out that way. 1024 * 1024 is just over a milion but it is then divided by (8*8), unless bitsPerByte is somehow defined as 1/8th and not 8 like it the var name would imply.

Comment: @AlecJoy That math computes the number of `uintptr_t` digits. The comment is correct: the limit is (around) a million bits. 16384 is the number of pointer-sized words used to store these bits. It's easy to test this on the console: `(1n << 1_048_000).toString(2).length` gives 1048001, whereas `(1n << 1_049_000).toString(2).length` throws a RangeError (in Safari/WebKit).

Answer (score 8):

It turns out it's `2^30 - 1` bits, or 2^(2^30) - 1. Any more bits and it wouldn't work. (I was unable to get the actual value, since bit shifts can't do that) To put that in comparison, there are more digits in that number than the population in the US (almost 2x)!

(Wolfram Alpha link for the [number of digits](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E2147483648%20-%201))

[image: Very big indeed!]

Tested on a modern Chrome browser.

Comment: Testing this in a Chromium based browser resulted in the console timing out until eventually the browser ran out of memory and crashed the page. It's quite interesting that it can detect a failure faster than display the result in the console.

Comment: @Codingale You can compute the number of bits and based on that generate a `RangeError`. Computing the number of bits is fast (i.e. it's calculating `n` in `2**n`).

Comment: With `2^30 - 1` bits, the highest number is `2^(2^30 - 1) - 1`, not `2^(2^30) -1`. Let's replace `2^30 - 1` by simply `3` to understand easily: with `2^3` bits (so 8 bits), the highest number is `2^8 - 1` (255). Also, I think your Wolfram Alpha link is wrong, it shows a number of bits of `2,147,483,648` instead of `1,073,741,823`.

Comment: Ouh, and something else: the priority of the operators is not what we expect: `1n<<30n-1n` is actually doing `1n<<29n`! What we want is `(1n<<30n)-1n`. And this shows that the highest number is actually `2^(2^30 - 1)` (there is not the last `- 1`). You can do the test yourself in Chrome: `try {1n<<((1n<<30n)-1n)}catch(e){e}` works and is equal to `0x8000...000`, but `try {(1n<<((1n<<30n)-1n))+1n}catch(e){e}` is over capacity.

Answer (score 7):

The size has arbitrary precision, per [4.3.25BigInt value](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-bigint-value), though, oddly not mentioned in the [20.2 BigInt Objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-bigint-value) section.

Here is a quick test program:

```
/* global BigInt */

let b = BigInt(10)
let exp = 1;
while (true) {
    console.log(`BigInt of 10^${exp} `);
    b = b * b;
    exp *= 2;
}
```

output with Node v13.2:

```
BigInt of 10^1
BigInt of 10^2
BigInt of 10^4
...
BigInt of 10^4194304
BigInt of 10^8388608
BigInt of 10^16777216
```

Performance really drags after about 10 to the millionth.

While there may be a platform specific maximum in a specific browser, the size requirement to show it would be large.  Even 10^10^6 takes over 300K to store.   You could extend the spec to add a limit with [Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), e.g., "limit is about 10^10^10^... 8 times", but, seriously, that would be silly.

Comment: In my case, (1n << 1048575n) yields a number after four seconds, but (1n << 1048576n) produces an immediate "RangeError: BigInt is too large to alocate"

Comment: Nice observation!

Answer (score 0):

So, running the following script in the console:

```js
let n = 1n;
let p = 1;

while(p<10001) {
  n *= 1267650600228229401496703205376n // 2^100
  console.log({p: p++})
  console.log(n)
}
```

does not "error" even though I'm multiplying by `1267650600228229401496703205376n` on each iteration, I easily got up to the equivalent of: 10000*100 bits (1,000,000 bits)

... however, the resulting value logged to the console is:
`78102406353244117148310442417059631533061780115528…123691650081257805509908275407049892733047013376n`, and I can't seem to retrieve any of the internal parts of the number (in the ...), so not sure how much use it is to me. In theory, it's still calculating fine. I'm sure I could have kept going. It took about 5 minutes or so to calculated all that up on my 2019 macbook pro.

(NOTE: I did not put in the `while(true)`, because it really started to lock up chrome after a while. I could not stop the algorithm and I could only shut down chrome by force, I decided to put in a max value that seemed relatively high and definitely good enough for anything most of us would want to deal with in the foreseeable future).

Point is, it looks like you can handle pretty big numbers this way.

Comment: Okay, I played around with it to verify:
`let n = 1n;
let p = 1;

while(p<10001) {
  n *= 1267650600228229401496703205376n // 2^100;
  p++;
}
console.log({p: p-1})
console.log(n);

let x = 1;
while(n>1) {
  n /= 2n;
  x++;
}
console.log({x: x-1});
`
helps prove the result (and it runs much faster)

Comment: I recently found that using `toString` on the number should give you the whole thing. I decided not to get the whole string of the one I generated above because it would be over 300,000 characters long.