# Javascript data type: BigInt vs Number

Tags: javascript

I just came across JavaScript's new data type `BigInt`. What are some of the real-time use cases where we have to use `BigInt` vs `Number`?

I also see that it doesn't have cross-browser compatibility at this point.

Comment: Refer to MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: any time you need a number bigger than 2<sup>53</sup> - 1

Comment: Best use-case will be using it for handling large numbers like times...

Comment: Why is the question closed? Shouldn't we make it easy for someone to refer to the difference between them directly here without reading whole doc?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

> `BigInt` is a built-in object that provides a way to represent whole
>   numbers larger than 2^53 - 1, which is the largest number JavaScript
>   can reliably represent with the `Number` primitive and represented by
>   the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` constant. `BigInt` can be used for
>   arbitrarily large integers.

**Difference:**

- `BigInt` cannot be used with methods in the built-in `Math` object and cannot be mixed with instances of `Number` in operations
- Because coercing between `Number` and `BigInt` can lead to loss of
  precision, it is recommended to only use `BigInt` when values greater
  than 2^53 are reasonably expected and not to coerce between the two
  types.

Answer (score 3):

The differences between `BigInt` and `Number`:

|  | `Number` | `BigInt` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Safe Range | `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` loses precision outside this range | Extremely large integers |
| Math | Supports `Math` object | basic arithmetic operations `+ * - % **` |
| Decimal vs. Integer | integers and decimals `1.00, 2.56` | only integers `1n, 2n` and `5n / 2 === 2n` |
| Syntax | No special syntax | Append `n` to the end, `new BigInt('100')` |
| Type Conversion | Automatically converts `Number` to `BigInt` in operations | Requires explicit conversion to `Number` for arithmetic with `Number` values |
| JSON | Supports by default | Not serializable by default |

> Use BigInt when you need to work with extremely large integers or require precise integer arithmetic without any loss of precision.

Answer (score 1):

The Number object uses a 64-bit floating-point format. With 64 bits allocated in memory, you have a sign bit, 11 bits for exponent, and 52 bits for the mantissa. Since you only have 52 bits to represent the mantissa, you can only safely represent integers between -(2^53 - 1) and 2^53 - 1. So what does this mean for Number and how does BigInt address it? Examples are usually helpful:

```
const nval1 = 9007199254740991 + 1
const nval2 = 9007199254740991 + 2
nval1 === nval2
# => true
```

Clearly, by using the comparison operator with numbers that extend beyond `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` leads to some unexpected results. Now let's try it with BigInt:

```
const bval1 =  9007199254740991n + 1n
const bval2 =  9007199254740991n + 2n
bval1 === bval2
# => false
```

In terms of practical use, BigInt was added to ES2020 to allow the representation of 64-bit integers, which are required for compatibility with many other programming languages and APIs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53335545/11107541

Comment: @user useful link, but not relevant to this answer.

Comment: "_BigInt was added to ES2020 to allow the representation of 64-bit integers_" I wouldn't say that was the only or main goal, since at least according to the spec it's for arbitrary size.

Comment: @user again you didn't deliver a point. I never said it was the "only or main goal". But it was certainly an important reason for its existance. The Number type cannot represent 64 bit integers so JavaScript needed  a type that would, as most other programming languages have such type. Your conjecture is useless, effectively an irrelevant comment.