# Parameters<T> helper for overloaded functions

Tags: typescript

If a function has overloads, the standard TypeScript `Parameters<T>` helper returns only types for the last version's arguments. Is there a way around this limitation?

```js
type StringNumber = `${number}`;
  
function add(a: StringNumber, b: StringNumber): number
function add(a: number, b: number): number
function add<T extends (StringNumber | number)>(a: T, b: T): number
{
  return Number(a) + Number(b);
}

type AddParameters = Parameters<typeof add> // => [a: number, b: number]

const addParams: AddParameters = ['1', '3']; // Error
```

**upd**

There were suggestions to abandon Paremetrs and describe types manually. But if the overloaded function is in a separate package, it will lead to code duplication. Is there any way to modify

```js
type Parameters<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;
```

to include all overloads?

For example, I would like to write a wrapper for a function that has overloads.

```js
import { originFn } from 'another-library';

function wrapperFn(...args: Parametrs<typeof originFn>) {
  return originFn(...args);
}
```

But I don't want to describe all the overloads manually.

Comment: might be just an example but why not define it simply as `add(a: StringNumber | number, b: StringNumber | number)` without overloads, the code doesn't care if you mix strings and numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Understood. Let's try another solution:

```
type StringNumber = `${number}`;

type Overloads<T> =
  T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2;
    (...args: infer A3): infer R3; (...args: infer A4): infer R4
  } ? [
    (...args: A1) => R1, (...args: A2) => R2,
    (...args: A3) => R3, (...args: A4) => R4
  ] : T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2;
    (...args: infer A3): infer R3
  } ? [
    (...args: A1) => R1, (...args: A2) => R2,
    (...args: A3) => R3
  ] : T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1; (...args: infer A2): infer R2
  } ? [
    (...args: A1) => R1, (...args: A2) => R2
  ] : T extends {
    (...args: infer A1): infer R1
  } ? [
    (...args: A1) => R1
  ] : any

type OverloadedParameters<T> =
  Overloads<T> extends infer O ?
  { [K in keyof O]: Parameters<Extract<O[K], (...args: any) => any>> }[keyof O] : never
  
function add(a: StringNumber, b: StringNumber): number
function add(a: number, b: number): number
function add<T extends (StringNumber | number)>(a: T, b: T): number
{
  return Number(a) + Number(b);
}

type AddParameters = OverloadedParameters<typeof add>;

const addParams: AddParameters = ['1', '3']; // no error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=39&ssc=41&pln=39&pc=42#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwHIFcC2AjC8UAvFAAYAkA3sjvvAL6kDcAUC6JFAPIBuBANgHsAhgBMAzgB4AKgD5iLKFGlQIAD2ARkEqJUVKoACgB0p4fFTiAXFBQAzAlACCARgCUN+44BKLpkdNjc0tPZAdCJwAmD1swn0jWAwCzC2tY8OcAZhivQm9M-xMUkPTHJwAWHLi88v16KAB+KABtfSUioNSbVzdieV8AGmTOkqjeon7Igbbh4LSnbL6ofKGOue7Kpe9apQBdKBsVdU1tcV0Zta7SiPdQjN9CwPXr52i7+MSDS5LcrKr7zJ1RotC5PK49LYuVZg0bRLZTUHFeaLCbLQF7A7KVQaLQ6PRJb5pX49d55PyzK7Et4vbyRIFNVoEmHzdyQ6FI7pw1G0-T7Q7Yk54xEjInVZy3Gkuekgpkc8XjfpSjE2YTIEBsDjQXgCESiCCiAAK5mE2AgmngUjkCiU2vgQjElvkx1xZ1+XEa+koLQA0rEoABrCAgQR2bi7GxG+Ams0EKQAUQ0UYAxsBJFxmt7duyRSq1QqoKqQLJ5PRmoHg6GuHyoMgIHx4PoWHZMMgU4hBMgC6JRIZhDY4Eg0Fg8AQhrh+wgUBhaAQYjQRw3m63gO3O2Ie32azP4GObPO6HPt02W22O13RDIBS6jAOp8O6FAAD5bhduWS9w675SHhcsfFQeAzUweBO3vAhe16ABqKAwPgQxcDcVh6A1cBoCcbtI2jc0zhIW17T1Q1jVNbDJE1ENz1kVgWCTDtxGAc9MOweYMKImMLWIFoAHIXE4oZOMyTjdn8AB6YSa0EVR4HgQR4CAA)

[GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32164)

Comment: How come "no error" in your last test? That is exactly where we would expect an error!

Comment: Sure, I've fixed the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify types for every overload manually. And then use its in overloads.

```
type StringNumber = `${number}`;

type ParamsStringNumber = [a: StringNumber, b: StringNumber];
type ParamsNumber = [a: number, b: number];
  
function add(...params: ParamsStringNumber): number
function add(...params: ParamsNumber): number
function add<T extends (StringNumber | number)>(a: T, b: T): number
{
  return Number(a) + Number(b);
}

type AddParameters = ParamsStringNumber | ParamsNumber;

const addParams: AddParameters = ['1', '3'] as AddParameters; // no error
```

Argument names will be displayed correctly:
[image]

Comment: I don't want to avoid Parameters<T>(can be replaced with a custom generic). This is an example. In the real case, the types are in another library. I don't want to duplicate them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's unnecessary to overcomplicate it. You accept numbers and also accept strings that represent some form of a number. Let's call this type `StringNumberOrNumber`. In this way, it will work not only with accepting only numbers or only numbers represented in strings but also with a mix of both.

```
// Type definitions
type StringNumber = `${number}`;
type StringNumberOrNumber = StringNumber | number;

// Function that takes two StringNumberOrNumber type parameters and returns a number
function add(a: StringNumberOrNumber, b: StringNumberOrNumber): number
{
  return Number(a) + Number(b);
}

// Examples of function calls

add(1, 2); // OK
add("1", "2"); // OK
add("1", 2); // OK
add(1, "2"); // OK

// Error cases

add(null, 2); // error (a)
add(1, null); // error (b)

add("a", 2); // error (a)
add(1, "b"); // error (b)

add("1a", 2); // error(a)
add(1, "2b"); // error(b)
```

[TypeScript interpreter marking errors on a photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI0Cx.png)

If you want to work exclusively with integers, use the [`bigint`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#bigint) type instead of [`number`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#number).

```
// Type definitions
type StringInteger = `${bigint}`;
type StringIntegerOrInteger = StringInteger | bigint;
```

#### More information

- [Data Types: BigInt vs Number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61583179/15167500) - StackOverflow Answer
- [TypeScript 4.8 will allow converting string literal types
  to other types like `number`, `bigint` or `boolean`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72669967/15167500) - StackOverflow Answer
- [TypeScript 4.8 - More specific inference
  for constrained 'infer' types in template literal types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48094) - GitHub