# Does BigInt represent number in 64-bit?

Tags: javascript, numbers, bigint

Is the value of `Number.MAX_VALUE` a limitation only for numbers of data type Number?
Doesn't BigInt have the same upper bound?

And another one question... Does BigInt represent number in 64-bit format IEEE-754?
Since the BigInt format represents large numbers, can the BigInt value take up more space than 64 bits?

Comment: The first sentence on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt): _"`BigInt` is a built-in object whose constructor returns a bigint primitive - also called a `BigInt` value, or sometimes just a `BigInt` - **to represent whole numbers larger than `2^53 - 1` (`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`), which is the largest number JavaScript can represent with a number primitive** (or Number value). BigInt values can be used **for arbitrarily large integers**."_

Comment: _"In JavaScript, [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/BigInt) is a numeric data type that can represent integers in the [arbitrary precision format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)."_

Comment: There is no upper limit specified for BIgInt, for more detail refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53335545/whats-the-biggest-bigint-value-in-js-as-per-spec

Comment: @Andreas: MDN is being surprisingly inaccurate in its wording there: the "largest number JavaScript can represent with a number primitive" is `Number.MAX_VALUE`, which is about 2^1024. `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is the biggest _whole_ (or "integer") number that can still be incremented by `1` without losing precision. Number values between MAX_SAFE_INTEGER and MAX_VALUE will be rounded (to 53 significant bits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Doesn't BigInt have the same upper bound?

No, BigInts have no specified limit. That said, realistically, there will always be implementation-defined limits (just like for Strings, Arrays, etc.). Currently, Chrome allows a billion bits, and Firefox allows a million bits. The expectation is that most realistically-occurring BigInts won't run into this limit.

> Does BigInt represent number in 64-bit format IEEE-754?

No, IEEE-754 is a floating-point format, so it's not useful for BigInts, which have integer values. Besides, they have "unlimited" precision.

> can the BigInt value take up more space than 64 bits?

Yes, BigInts can consume a lot more than 64 bits. For example, a BigInt with a thousand bits (such as `2n ** 999n`) will need (about) a thousand bits of memory (likely rounded up to the next multiple of 4 or 8 bytes, plus a small object header, specifics depend on the engine).